# callgrind output in specific file

Tags: valgrind, callgrind

I want to redirect the output of callgrind to a file name `call_grind.txt`, but when ever I try to do that, a file is generated but there is no output inside that file.

For example:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/tmp/call_grind.txt <program name>
```

Also, I'm not getting any `callgrind.out.<pid>` file in my system where it should normally be located.

According to my understanding, if I run the below command it should create the `callgrind.out.<pid> file`:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind <program name>
```

So, how do I use the tool and also how to read the output file?

Answer (score 5):

The `callgrind.out.<pid>` or the file you specified with `--callgrind-out-file` will be created if valgrind finished running successfully. Check the process exit code to make sure it is 0 to see if succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `callgrind_control -d` to explicitly flush the output.

[callgrind_control](https://linux.die.net/man/1/callgrind_control) also allows you to control when to start/stop instrumentation (and a couple other things)